# Sending text from fragment to custom view where I want to use canvas.drawText

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-canvas, android-view

I am new to Android and want to pass some text from a fragment to a custom view. Inside the custom view I want to use `canvas.drawText` to position the string. The reason I want to use `canvas.drawText` is for consistency with the position of some graphics.

What is the procedure for this?

Just to clarify, my fragment has something like this:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private TextView view;
private TextView txtBox;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);
    txtBox = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtBox);
            String myString = "testing";
            txtBox.setText(myString);
    return view;
    }
}
```

I have a fragment_layout.xml file for View1 (my custom view):

```
<com.example.stuff.View1
    android:id="@+id/TxtBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The call I am wish to make inside the custom view:

```
public class View1 extends TextView {

    //constructors:
    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int ds) {
        super(context, ats, ds);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
...
canvas.drawText(myString, margin1, margin2, paint);
....
}
```

...and what I want is to get `myString` from Fragment1.java to the View1.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the answers I received [here (using setters/getters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906902/supplying-text-from-fragment-to-custom-textview) and [here (getting rid of the resulting NullPointer exception from mis-defined layout calls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913973/nullpointerexception-when-accessing-relativelayout-from-a-custom-view).

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `com.example.stuff.View1` custom view dynamically, i.e. dont add it in the xml but add it using the code. And then you could pass the text in the `constructor` of the `com.example.stuff.View1`.
Other way could be to create a method in the `com.example.stuff.View1` class and set the text there. For example

```
public class View1 extends TextView {

    //constructors:
    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int ds) {
        super(context, ats, ds);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void setMyText(String string) {
        myString=string;
    }
...
canvas.drawText(myString, margin1, margin2, paint);
....
}
```

then in your code do something like this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);
    txtBox = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtBox);
    String myString = "testing";
    txtBox.setMyText(myString);
```

Comment: Can you supply more detail? Perhaps example code? I've edited my question above. I'm wondering how to supply text through the constructor of View1? Thanks.