# Supplying text from fragment to custom TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

How do I set up a constructor in a custom TextView to be able to pass text from a fragment?

In other words, I'm confused how to send text from my fragment (Fragment1) to the custom view (View1):

```
public class View1 extends TextView {

    //constructors:
    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int ds) {
        super(context, ats, ds);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public View1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
...
canvas.drawText(myString, margin1, margin2, paint); //myString is from Fragment1
....
}
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890491/sending-text-from-fragment-to-custom-view-where-i-want-to-use-canvas-drawtext), but didn't really get much help. Example code would go a long way towards clearing up my confusion. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if it is good practice to ask the same question again just after 20 hours.

Comment: Why not use `getText().toString()` to get the String?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not stating the question well enough which is why I'm trying to ask again -- the variable (which is a string) is calculated in the fragment. But how do I get it into the custom view? I don't see how getText().toString() will help since it's already a string...

Comment: The best starting point for good answers is a good question. Since you already have another question, it would have been way better to improve on that question instead of opening the same question again.

Comment: @lynvie Just because the fragment holds the String, doesn't mean that the TextView knows about it. Which is why you'd use `setText()`.

Comment: @sstn, I edited the question several times, actually (which is why I referenced it) but I wasn't getting any more views. So I assumed the question was dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending a `TextView` anyway. As A--C mentioned, you can use `getText()`, as well as `setText()` to get and set the text.

In your context, I am not sure if it is a good idea to use `TextView` to implement your custom view/widget. View might be a better starting point, as `TextView` carries all kind of stuff around for formatting, icon/drawable display, click/button logic etc.

You need to define the standard constructors if you want to be able to have the system instantiate/inflate your components from an XML layout. Then you can use standard getters/setters for your data, same way as all other controls do it.

If you instantiate your widget/view yourself (in your code), you are free to define whatever constructors you want to (I believe).

Comment: Ok, I guess my real confusion here is how to get the string out of the fragment? I can't make a call like Fragment.myString because fragments only take default constructors.

Comment: @lynvie So what is the problem with a setter method? This is how all other widgets do it. I don't understand why this should not work here.

Comment: ok, I will relook at the code in a few hours as I had to leave. Thanks for the help.